# Null Pointer Exception while working with fragments in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am working on functionality in which I want to send data from send fragment to another. I am setting arguments in one fragment say "A Fragment" and getting it from another say "B Fragment" but the problem is this when I  jump to "B fragment" from "C Fragment" which does not contain that value then my app crashes and throws error **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**

My Code:

**Fragment A**

```
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("advisor_id", advisor_id);

            FragmentMicroLearningArticlesList fragmentMicroLearningArticlesList = new FragmentMicroLearningArticlesList();
            fragmentMicroLearningArticlesList.setArguments(bundle);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragmentMicroLearningArticlesList);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**Fragment B**

```
      String  advisor_id = "";
   if(getArguments().getString("advisor_id") != null )
    {
        advisor_id = getArguments().getString("advisor_id");
    }
    else {
        advisor_id = "";
    }
```

[image: Logs]

Comment: It is pretty clear that you cannot read the arguments when they have not been set before. What are you actually asking?

Comment: Set the Arguments in fragment B also. And get in fragment B.

Comment: Just like henry said your arguments is null Maybe you should add a check if your arguments are null then don't do anything if not get the value ?

Comment: How can I handle this  that If I am getting value from one but not from another

Comment: @Umair I am checking null check the above code but it is crashing

Comment: where you wrote code for get value from argument? post your full code of fragment B

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper well your check is for the string value not for the arguments :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @NileshRathod everytime not duplicate question just for NP.

Answer (score 2):

As the error says check if argument is null...

```
if( getArguments() != null && getArguments().getString("advisor_id") != null )
```

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper are you able to get value from bundle?

Comment: Very Good... enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Fragment B

```
  String  advisor_id = "";
   if(getArguments()!= null )
    {
        advisor_id = getArguments().getString("advisor_id");
    }
    else {
        advisor_id = "";
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of the `else` statement? You've already initialised the `String` - this would only make sense if you have `final String advisor_id;` instead of `String  advisor_id = "";` and even then `advisor_id` could still be initialised to `null`